# How to fast insert data from Python 3 to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, turbodbc

I'm having issues quickly inserting large volumes of data from Python3 into SQL Server.

The target table has 9 columns with 3 indexes and 1 primary key.

The below code works but it's a lot slower than I would like. See timing below:

```
-- 1,000 records
In [35]: %time connection_factory.executemany(sql, args)
CPU times: user 30.2 ms, sys: 40.9 ms, total: 71.1 ms
Wall time: 3.54 s

-- 5,000 records
In [46]: %time connection_factory.executemany(sql, args)
CPU times: user 110 ms, sys: 55.8 ms, total: 166 ms
Wall time: 17 s
```

I've tried using sql_alchemy and am currently using Turbodbc - but open to anything else that works faster.

Below is a sample of my code

```
from turbodbc import connect, make_options

class ConnectionFactory:
def __init__(self):
    self.connection = self.initialize()

@staticmethod
def initialize():
    options = make_options(autocommit=True)
    return connect(driver="FREETDS",
                   server="",
                   port="",
                   database="",
                   uid="",
                   pwd="",
                   turbodbc_options=options)

def execute(self, query, params=None):
    try:
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, params)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        return

def executemany(self, query, params=None):
    try:
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(query, params)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        return


sql = """
INSERT INTO table1 (value1,
                    value2,
                    value3,
                    value4,
                    value5,
                    value6,
                    value7)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); """

args = df.to_records().tolist()
connection_factory = ConnectionFactory()
connection_factory.executemany(sql, args)
```

Is anyone familiar with this exact combination of SQL Server and python that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is the data being loaded from?  A record-file?

Comment: from a pandas dataframe in memory. I showed the conversion in the bottom of the code, but it's being hidden by the scrolling window.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake, I posted information about mySQL.  You're looking for msSQL.

**Here is an equivalent bulk insert statement for msSQL:**

```
BULK INSERT MyTable
    FROM 'path\myfile.csv'
    WITH 
        (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

**There are a few options:**

You may write your data to a .csv file and then leverage mySql's very fast `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.

**OR**

You may also use another form of the insert command, which is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);
```

**See these optimization links:**

- [Load Data Infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- [mySQL Insert Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you already have function for execute(). it should be faster same to bulk insert.

```
args= ', '.join(map(str, df.to_records().tolist()))

sql = "
INSERT INTO table1 (value1,
                    value2,
                    value3,
                    value4,
                    value5,
                    value6,
                    value7)
VALUES {}".format(args)

connection_factory = ConnectionFactory()
connection_factory.execute(sql)
```

Create new method to execute query from string without params.

```
def execute2(self, query):
    try:
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        return
```

Comment: ahhh.. very creative. Let me try it and see how it compares. I'll report back findings. Thank you.